# What is the origin of the expression "the clothes they stood up in"?

Tags: etymology

I am specifically interested in the date it was first used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the exact date it was first used, but I found out that the oldest (or one of the oldest) example(s) date(s) back to the middle of the 19th century:

> “Get up their luggage and send them ashore,” was the order given—but
>   the old man said they need not trouble themselves, they had no
>   luggage, nothing but **the clothes they stood up in**, and tin cans for
>   their day's allowance of water."

Littell's Living Age, Volume 26 (1850)